# collapse rows by values of another column

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to plot a spectra with my data, where I need to integrate all data from the x coordinate. So far, the code I'm using is the following:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.plot(
    dft.filter((pl.col("x") < 1_000) & (pl.col("t") < 15_000)).select(pl.col("x"))[:npts],
    dft.filter((pl.col("x") < 1_000) & (pl.col("t") < 15_000)).select(pl.col("t"))[:npts],
    ".",
    markersize=0.01,
);
```

producing this plot:
[image: plot]

What I need to plot is all data from the x coordinate that correspond to the same "t" summed into a single value.

Is this the best way to achieve it:

```
grouped_data = (
    dft
    .filter((pl.col("x") < 1_000) & (pl.col("t") < 15_000))
    .groupby("t")
    .agg(pl.col("x").sum().alias("sum_x"))
)

# Plot the aggregated data
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.plot(
    grouped_data.select(pl.col("t")),
    grouped_data.select(pl.col("sum_x")),
    ".",
    markersize=1,
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the code above achieve the desired result? The only thing I'd change in this case would be to call `ax.plot` with `data=grouped_data`, `x="t"`, and `y="sum_x"`.

Comment: You're filtering x and t to the limits of the graph but you're actually graphing the sum of x after the filter. Without knowing what your data is, it seems the filter should be after the aggregation if the filter is actually related to the graph axis limits. In the first example you're subsetting to what I'd guess is a number of points with `[:npts]` you should use `sample(npts)` to do that unless there's a specific reason why you'd take the first n rather than a random subset of n.